# How to (server-side) read cookies with cgi and bash?

Tags: bash, cookies, cgi, server-side

I want to read the cookies I have set on the client with cgi and bash. However, by searching around I found that the suggestion is to use jQuery. The problem is that I want to check the cookie server-side and not client-side.

I need the cookie for implementing a login-based authentication of my users. The session should be timed-out by the server and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code to display cookies

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Content-Type: text/plain'
echo
echo $HTTP_COOKIE
```